# virtual host for xampp on Mac

Tags: apache, vhosts

in my httpd-vhost.conf on macos 10.15.4,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/theb/"
    ServerName theb.localhost
    ServerAlias www.theb.localhost
    #DirectoryIndex index.html
    <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/theb">
        Require all granted              
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride none
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/theb.local-error_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

I have also included the virtual host in httpd.conf

```
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Then in the host file, i have

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   www.theb.localhost
```

The issue im facing now with these configs is that whenever i browse the site in my browser,

http://www.theb.localhost, i will then be redirected to http://www.theb.localhost/dashboard ( which is the xampp default project folder). did i miss something out??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Restart Apache. Hopefully that will work.
2. If you have downloaded the VM version of Xampp (The one that gets mounted) then this wont work as it doesn't have access to your local files, get the non VM one here https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Mac%20OS%20X/7.4.6/xampp-osx-7.4.6-0-installer.dmg/download

Comment: Somehow, after trying the version of xampp 7.4.6 that was suggested by @Tristanisginger it still somehow fails. After that, ive reinstall back my original version of non-VM of xampp 7.2, the virtual host was put back the same as the config that I posted, it then is working. Not too sure what solved here but im goin to mark this as solved.